# NodeJS and Mysql Query Fetch

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

Hey iam new in NodeJS and i would like to know .. How to Fetch an mysql Query like PHP HERE

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $fetch['Username'];
}
```

### How it looks like in NodeJS ?

**And one more thing**

iam using ExpressJS And my users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../database');
/* GET users page. */
router.get('/' , function(req, res, next) {
     db.query('SELECT * FROM accounts', function(err, rows) {
         // Fields > Return Table Fields ( Name , type , length .... )
         // rows > return Rows Data

               db.query("select * from comments where user = ?",
                     [rows[0].Username],
                     function(err, rowx) {

                         console.log('User Comments : '+rowx);
                         console.log('Usernames : '+rows.Username);
                     });
 if (err) throw err;
             numRows = rows.length;
             res.render('users', {
                 title: 'Users Table',
                 rowCount: numRows,
                 rowsData: rows
             });

         }); // END OF Query
     });

module.exports = router;
```

**how to get The Data in Comments Table using the Username from the accounts table ?**

Answer (score 0):

you should use async package to use nodejs like php your first code block in nodejs can be like this :

```
var async=require('async');
async.auto(
{
   getAccounts:function(cb,results){
      db.query('SELECT * FROM accounts', function(err, rows) {
           cb(null,rows)
     })
   },
   showRows:['getAccounts',function(cb,results){
       var accounts=results.getAccounts;
       for(var account in accounts){
          console.log(accounts[accont])
       }
  }]
   },
   function(err,allResult)
   {
    }
)
```